# Arduino IDE compiling for non-arduino AVR boards

Tags: arduino-ide, pins, avr, port-mapping

Using:

- Arduino IDE 1.8.2
- the board manager from https://mcudude.github.io/MiniCore/package_MCUdude_MiniCore_index.json
- an ATmega168P MCU in TQFP

I was able to run my code successfully by modifying the file

`[ardunoIDE]\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard\pins_arduino.h`

building and then flashing the MCU with `avrdude`.

Is there any way to have Arduino IDE build system pick its `pins_arduino.h` file from somewhere else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, MiniCore is a self-contained hardware package. After installing MiniCore select one of the MiniCore boards in the Arduino IDE's **Tools > Board** menu and the Arduino IDE will automatically use the pins_arduino.h file included with MiniCore. There is no need to modify any file in the Arduino IDE folder or any other folder.

Comment: Arduino IDE does not use the pins_arduino.h file included with MiniCore. Can you give me its path on your installation so I can at least check it is there ?

Comment: Do this:  
Select a MiniCore board from the Tools > Board menu, File > Examples > AVR C code examples > Blink, Sketch > Show Sketch Folder, Navigate up 4 folder levels to the 1.0.3 folder. The pins_arduino.h file used for MiniCore boards is located under that folder in the variants/standard folder.